# Large number of values in ssrs parameter giving error while viewing report

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I am viewing SSRS report through asp.net reportviewer, I have 4 multi-value parameters in it, from them, two contains more than 600 values each.

Report loads correctly, but when i click on View Report Button, it gives "sys.webforms.pagerequestmanagerservererrorexception" error.

I have used below settings and restarted Reporting services also but its not working.

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="10000" />
   <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="10000" />
</appSettings>
```

and if i restrict query with top 50 in that both parameter, report works fine.

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved now. let me share it so it can help someone else also.

I have added appsetting mentioned in Question in Report Server web.config only, now i have added it in web.config of ASP.NET web site where Report viewer is used and it is working fine now.

Thanks to all for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

If the report viewer relies on query strings for rendering, this could be an issue with the size of your query string: for example, in IE, such limit is 2048 characters.

Nevertheless, I think you probably shouldn't be passing 600 arguments around; one viable option would be creating a temporary table, filling it with your values and changing the report for reading from it, instead of receiving multiple parameters.

Comment: I am not passing 600 arguments every time, first i check count with help of hidden parameter, if its 600, i am not passing it in the query.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. I thought this problem was occurring only when you passed more than 600 values.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, perhaps try splitting those parameters to reduce the number of values in a single dropdown. For instance, `Cities A-H, Cities I-P, Cities R-Z`.